# Is there a method to read json file from another heroku app?

Tags: node.js, json, heroku

Is there a method for read json file from another heroku app?

Comment: Hi BlackDestiny, and welcome to SO. Of course there is, please be more specific. How do you obtain this JSON, does it come from an API endpoint? How do you intend to read it?

Comment: I have two apps on heroku, one is a discord bot ( made with discord.js) and a website.
In the discord bot app i have a config json file, with some config values.
From the website app i want to get the config file values like fs.readFile function, so how i can?

Comment: It is not possible to read a json file from another Heroku app. You will have to expose the json file through an API/webserver.

Comment: I think @vodolaz095 got it right, alternatively you can choose to serve the config.json from your discord bot app although it doesn't sound like good practice.

Comment: Thanx for all suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

in discord bot, you can expose config.json via webserver used for recieving hooks.

in website app, you can get this data using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) nodejs package or similiar ones.

Comment: Can you link me a tutorial for do this?